# Troubles with a node.js server and socket.io on cyclic

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io, real-time

I want to create a little web application for a school project which is supposed to show the dashboard regarding a sports game. Therefore, different people can access it and add/subtract points. I created this application using socket.io and node.js. It runs perfectly on the localhost but I also deployed it via cyclic and there it does not run at all. My website runs under https://zealous-frog-tutu.cyclic.app and I keep getting the errors `WebSocket connection to 'wss://zealous-frog-tutu.cyclic.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=n-nRy6LHG-eD8QT3AAAR' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.` and `WebSocket connection to 'wss://zealous-frog-tutu.cyclic.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=7ATD-aEznbKrmdzCAAAM' failed: There was a bad response from the server.`. It also says `{"code": 1, "message": "Session ID unknown"}`. You can find my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/FyZe20/Points).

I already asked ChatGPT but it could not help me. It said to write `const socket = io('https://zealous-frog-tutu.cyclic.app');` on the client-side but this did not change anything directly. Furthermore, I also tried

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "https://zealous-frog-tutu.cyclic.app", // Update with your actual client's origin
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        credentials: true
    },
    transports: ['websocket'] // Explicitly specify the WebSocket transport
});
```

but the error messages did not disappear either. I think the issue has something to do multiple socket.io events on the node.js server but I do not really know what else to do because I only have very little coding experience.

Does anyone know what I need to do? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me once when I created a live code editor and it uses socket. Everything ran fine on localhost but as soon as I hosted it manually on aws(means I configured the server and reverse proxy myself), then it had some problems with the socket part. Rest of the application which contained HTTP requests worked fine but this socket part was not. So, I decided to not use AWS instead I chose railway or render(I don't remember exactly as earlier this application was hosted on heroku but they turned their free tier off) these platforms (Saas) couldn't host my WS part properly or they were saying that socket functionality is not supported in free tiers. So i decided to switch back to AWS. Then I found that I've only configured my nginx to work with http requests but not with WS requests. I don't remember the exact steps but after googling amd configuring nginx my WS part worked fine. Now in your case, since cyclic is a SaaS where you're just told to upload the source code, I don't think you can do much on that in free tier. Or you've to find their ws service part.